# Powershell script to Find and replace Particular value in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, powershell-2.0

I have a csv file in path and i need to fetch the file and do Find & Replace **$(dollar)** value to **,(comma)** using PowerShell script. please help me on the script .

**CSV file**

```
id|name|place
1|adam$|USA
2|john|USA
3|Jack$|England
```

**Expected output** : Need to do Find & Replace **$(dollar)** value to **,(comma)** under **name** column

```
id|name|place
1|adam,|USA
2|john|USA
3|Jack,|England
```

Command Used

```
Import-csv D:\CSV\Customer.csv
ForEach-Object {  $_.name -replace '$',',' }
```

i didn't got any error nor the expected changes. **i need to update the values in existing CSV file**

Below Answer by **Zett42** works but

```
(Import-Csv D:\CSV\Customer.csv -Delimiter '|') |
    Select-Object 'id', 
                  @{ n = 'name'; e = { $_.name.Replace('$', ',') } },
                  'place' |
    Export-Csv D:\CSV\Customer.csv -Delimiter '|'
```

but the tricky part is we are replacing the **,(Comma)** value and rewriting the CSV files again, so CSV file creation part considers the value after  ,(comma) as new column and move the value to column B instead of Column A.

**Before :**

[image]

**After :**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```sh
Import-Csv D:\CSV\Customer.csv -Delimiter '|' |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.name = $_.name.Replace('$', ',')
        $_  # Implicit output - gets passed to Export-Csv
    } |
    Export-Csv D:\CSV\Customer_new.csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

- In your code, there is a pipe symbol `|` missing at the end of the `Import-Csv` line.
- As the CSV uses non-standard delimiters, you have to specify them using `-Delimiter`.
- Also, the `-replace` operator doesn't modify its arguments, so you are actually just outputting the replaced value. Also, `'$'` has special meaning in regular expression patterns, which `-replace` uses, so you have to backslash-escape it or use the `String.Replace()` method as I did in the code above. The `String.Replace()` method doesn't use RegEx.
- In the `ForEach-Object` script block, the `$_` at the end is necessary to output the current object again, so it gets send down the pipeline to `Export-Csv`. Otherwise `Export-Csv` wouldn't have anything to output.

---

Alternative code using `Select-Object`:

```sh
Import-Csv D:\CSV\Customer.csv -Delimiter '|' |
    Select-Object 'id', 
                  @{ n = 'name'; e = { $_.name.Replace('$', ',') } },
                  'place' |
    Export-Csv D:\CSV\Customer_new.csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

To **overwrite the existing file** instead of creating a new file use the group operator `()` to collect all data in memory and close the old file before overwriting the file:

```
(Import-Csv D:\CSV\Customer.csv -Delimiter '|') |
    Select-Object 'id', 
                  @{ n = 'name'; e = { $_.name.Replace('$', ',') } },
                  'place' |
    Export-Csv D:\CSV\Customer.csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

IMO this is somewhat cleaner as you don't need to modify the current pipeline object and don't need to explicitly forward it to the next command.

It uses a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) to generate the new value for the `name` column. In this case we don't need to assign the result back to `$_.name` because calculated properties automatically assign the output from the script block to the property.

Comment: @zerr42 thanks for the answer .is there any option to update the value in existing  CSV file without Creating New CSV File ?

Comment: @HellBoy Added solution to overwrite existing file.

Comment: yes it works , but the tricky part is we are replacing the ,(Comma) value and rewriting the CSV files again,so CSV file creation considers the data after ,(comma) as new column and place data to column B instead of Column A.

Comment: @HellBoy When you import CSV in Excel or OpenOffice, you could specify delimiter `|`. Add parameter `-NoTypeInformation` to `Export-Csv` to remove the first line.

Comment: yes it removes first line . is there any option/logic to replace data in CSV file without rewriting the file again. Rewriting CSV file make the format to consider value after comma as new column